# How to rename more than 1 file during upload ? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form to upload about 5 files,
lets say it is a photo of the person who is registering and other document about him.

now i'm creating a folder for every registered user with their name ( btw, is it good thing to do? ), and i want to rename each file with the right name let say photo,document A,document B and etc.

my current code

```
        $upload_setting['upload_path'] = './uploads/'.$_POST['name'].'/';
        $upload_setting['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|pdf';
        $upload_setting['max_size'] = 5000; // 5 MB
        $upload_setting['file_name'] = $_POST['name']; // this define the uploaded file name


        $this->load->library('upload', $upload_setting);


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('form');

        }


        else{
            if (!is_dir('./uploads/'.$_POST['name'].'/')) {
                mkdir('./uploads/'.$_POST['name'].'/', 0777, TRUE);

            }


            $this->member->register($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));

            $this->upload->do_upload('photo');
            $this->upload->do_upload('document-A');
            $this->upload->do_upload('document-B');
```

Also how can i let them free to upload JPG,PDF,DOC ? 
i have to link these file in their profile page.
how can i know what extension they upload for each document ?

Please let me know if you have any suggestion or best practice to do this upload and then display each upload in their profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To know the extension of your file you can use-

```
    $newname= "name";
    $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
    $file_newname = $newname.'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
```

To Upload-

```
if( $_FILES['picture']['name'] )
             {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'images/receipt/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['file_name'] = $file_newname; //Here your file is being renamed
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('picture'))
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    return false;
                }
             }
```